# Program runs when accessed directly, but not when accessed through symlink

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I have installed a ruby application to `/home/anp/tools` and then created a symbolic link as follows:

```
ln -s /home/anp/tools/wwan /usr/bin/wwan
```

If I execute `~/tools/wwan`, it runs perfectly fine.
If I try to run it from the symbolic link, I get an error saying

> cannot load such file -- lib/wwan

Shouldn't this work as is? Is the symbolic link causing problems when the program tries to resolve relative file paths?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the symbolic link causing problems when the program tries to resolve relative file paths?

It may. It most likely is in this case.

Plausible scenario when you run `~/tools/wwan`:

1. The shell expands `~` and you really run `/home/anp/tools/wwan`.
2. The tool starts. It knows it is `/home/anp/tools/wwan` (e.g. because of [`argv[0]`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315812/108618)).
3. The tool finds the directory portion of the above string and changes its own working directory to it: `/home/anp/tools/`.
4. The tool refers to an additional asset via a relative path: `lib/wwan`. The asset is indeed in `/home/anp/tools/lib/wwan`, so it works.

But when you run `/usr/bin/wwan` or `wwan` (with `/usr/bin` being in `$PATH`), the scenario starts with `/usr/bin/wwan` and ends with `/usr/bin/lib/wwan` which doesn't exist as a file. The asset is not there.

The details may vary but such a problem with a symbolic link indicates the tool doesn't dereference the link when it should. If it did, it would always work with `/home/anp/tools/wwan` as if you run `/home/anp/tools/wwan`. I would say what you experienced is a bug.

One way to deal with this is to improve the tool itself (edit its code) so it properly finds its real path.

Another way is to use a wrapper script instead of a symlink. Remove the symlink and create a script under the name `/usr/bin/wwan`. The content of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /home/anp/tools/wwan "$@"
```

Make it executable. Now if you call `/usr/bin/wwan`, the script will `exec` to `/home/anp/tools/wwan` and this will be the string the tool will work with, so it should work. All (zero or more) arguments you provide for `/usr/bin/wwan` will be passed to `/home/anp/tools/wwan` thanks to `"$@"`.

Notes:

- `/usr/bin/` is a system-wide location for executables. Linking from there to a tool that resides in your home directory is not a good practice in general; the same for wrapping.
- A wrapper script is a separate regular file. Its ownership and permissions are independent from these of the target executable. Set them right.